# GWT external JavaScript integration (OpenSeadragon) problem with EventHandlers after full screen

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gxt, openseadragon

in my GWT-Project I currently integrating an external JavaScript package OpenSeadragon (see [here](https://openseadragon.github.io/)), which is a ImageViewer with zoo, rotate and fullscreen function. It mostly works well so far. The only anoying problem is, that nothing is clickable any more after coming back from the fullscreen mode. 
I think the reason for this greatly unwanted behaviour is, that openseadragon moves all other Dom-Elements away, when it shows fullscreen (see [this bug](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1127) for more details).
The code is the following:

```
    public native void createZoomeImage(String ressource, Element where, SingleImageEditor sie)
/*-{
    var viewer =  $wnd.OpenSeadragon({
        element: where,
        showRotationControl: true,
        prefixUrl: "scripts/openseadragon-bin-2.4.2/images/",
        debugMode: true,
        tileSources: ressource
    });
    viewer.addHandler("full-screen", function (data) {
        if(data.fullScreen == false){
                $wnd.activatepanel(sie);
        }
    });
}-*/;
```

The Handler was added by me, because firstly I thought, it would be enough to activate the panel again. (`$wnd.activatepanel(sie);` does refere to a java method, which does exactly this). Yet this did not change a thing.
Now, my question: Does anybody know an elegant way to refresh the eventhandlers in GWT or antoher workaround?

Sincerely,

Erik

Comment: if this project uses some new/recent version of gwt i would recommend moving from jsni and use jsinterop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out:

```
        var viewer =  $wnd.OpenSeadragon({
        element: where,
        showRotationControl: true,
        prefixUrl: "scripts/openseadragon-bin-2.4.2/images/",
        tileSources: ressource,
    });
    viewer.addHandler("pre-full-page", function (data) {
            data.preventDefaultAction=true;
            openFullscreen();
    });
    function openFullscreen() {
        if (where.requestFullscreen) {
            where.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (where.mozRequestFullScreen) { 
            where.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (where.webkitRequestFullscreen) { 
            where.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (where.msRequestFullscreen) {
            where.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
```